# How do I display all the date of birth from a node?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml document with 3 dates of birth, **current**, **approximate** and **just date**. I want to display the 3 dates as output.

**My xml code**

```
<Party ID="76" InternalPartyID="18">
    <Gender Word="F ">Female</Gender>
    <ApproximateDOB>03/4/1956</ApproximateDOB>
    <DateOfBirth Current="true">05/21/1956</DateOfBirth>
    <DateOfBirth>04/21/1956</DateOfBirth>
</Party>
```

**My XSLT code**

```
<!--Respondent -->
   <xsl:for-each select="RespondentPartyID">
   <xsl:for-each select="//CaseParty[(@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID) and (Connection[(@Word='RSP') ])]">
   <xsl:for-each select="//Party[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]">
<xsl:call-template name="Respondent">
   <xsl:with-param name="pProtectionOrderID">
   <xsl:value-of select="$vProtectionOrderID"/>
   </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>

<!--Respondent Template-->
<xsl:template name="Respondent">
    <xsl:param name="pProtectionOrderID"/>
<ext:Respondent>
<!--Guardian -->
    <xsl:for-each select="//CaseParty[(Connection[(@Word='GRD')])][1]">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Party[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]">
            <xsl:call-template name="Guardian"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <ext:PersonBirthDate>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="DateOfBirth[@Current='true']">
                <xsl:attribute name="ext:ApproximateDateIndicator">false</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="ext:CurrentIndicator">true</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="mscef:formatDate(string(DateOfBirth[@Current='true']))"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ApproximateDOB">
                <xsl:attribute name="ext:ApproximateDateIndicator">true</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="ext:CurrentIndicator">true</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="mscef:formatDate(string(ApproximateDOB))"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </ext:PersonBirthDate>
</ext:Respondent>
```

**How do I change my xslt code so that the output looks like the one below. Right now I my xslt returns only current date of birth:**

```
<ext:PersonBirthDate ext:approximateDateIndicator="false" ext:currentIndicator="true">1956-05-21</ext:PersonBirthDate>
<ext:PersonBirthDate ext:approximateDateIndicator="true" ext:currentIndicator="false">1956-03-04</ext:PersonBirthDate>
<ext:PersonBirthDate ext:approximateDateIndicator="false" ext:currentIndicator="false">1956-04-21</ext:PersonBirthDate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider having a template match for each possible 'Date of Birth' element. Something like this:

```
   <xsl:template match="DateOfBirth">
      <ext:PersonBirthDate>
         <xsl:attribute name="approximateDateIndicator">false</xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:attribute name="currentIndicator">false</xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </ext:PersonBirthDate>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="DateOfBirth[@Current='true']">
      <ext:PersonBirthDate>
         <xsl:attribute name="approximateDateIndicator">false</xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:attribute name="currentIndicator">true</xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </ext:PersonBirthDate>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ApproximateDOB">
      <ext:PersonBirthDate>
         <xsl:attribute name="approximateDateIndicator">true</xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:attribute name="currentIndicator">false</xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </ext:PersonBirthDate>
   </xsl:template>
```

Then you can change your existing XSLT code to this, which should then output all three dates.

```
   <xsl:apply-templates select="ApproximateDOB|DateOfBirth" />
```

It is clearly quite repetitive to have so many templates, but it should be no trouble to combine the templates into one.

Try this XSLT for starters:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ext="ext">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="Party">
       <ext:Respondent>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="ApproximateDOB|DateOfBirth" />
       </ext:Respondent>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ApproximateDOB|DateOfBirth">
      <ext:PersonBirthDate 
            approximateDateIndicator="{local-name() = 'ApproximateDOB'}" 
            currentIndicator="{@Current = 'true'}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </ext:PersonBirthDate>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) to further simplify the code.

When the above XSLT is applied to the following XML

```
<Party ID="76" InternalPartyID="18">
    <Gender Word="F ">Female</Gender>
    <ApproximateDOB>03/4/1956</ApproximateDOB>
    <DateOfBirth Current="true">05/21/1956</DateOfBirth>
    <DateOfBirth>04/21/1956</DateOfBirth>
</Party>
```

The following is output

```
<ext:Respondent xmlns:ext="ext">
    <ext:PersonBirthDate approximateDateIndicator="true" currentIndicator="false">03/4/1956</ext:PersonBirthDate>
    <ext:PersonBirthDate approximateDateIndicator="false" currentIndicator="true">05/21/1956</ext:PersonBirthDate>
    <ext:PersonBirthDate approximateDateIndicator="false" currentIndicator="false">04/21/1956</ext:PersonBirthDate>
</ext:Respondent>
```

(I have left out the date formatting, because I don't have the extension function to test locally)

EDIT: To fit this into your XSLT code, you would do this

```
<!--Respondent -->
<xsl:for-each select="RespondentPartyID">
   <xsl:for-each select="//CaseParty[(@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID) and (Connection[(@Word='RSP') ])]">
   <xsl:for-each select="//Party[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]">
<xsl:call-template name="Respondent">
   <xsl:with-param name="pProtectionOrderID">
   <xsl:value-of select="$vProtectionOrderID"/>
   </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>

<!--Respondent Template-->
<xsl:template name="Respondent">
   <xsl:param name="pProtectionOrderID"/>
   <ext:Respondent>
   <!--Guardian -->
    <xsl:for-each select="//CaseParty[(Connection[(@Word='GRD')])][1]">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Party[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]">
            <xsl:call-template name="Guardian"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ApproximateDOB|DateOfBirth" />
 </ext:Respondent>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ApproximateDOB|DateOfBirth">
      <ext:PersonBirthDate 
            approximateDateIndicator="{local-name() = 'ApproximateDOB'}" 
            currentIndicator="{@Current = 'true'}">
         <xsl:value-of select="mscef:formatDate(string(.))"/>
      </ext:PersonBirthDate>
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I have added the entire xslt code for the respondent whom I am trying to output the date of birth, and also approximate date of birth.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how it fits into your XSLT code

Comment: Thanks so much Tim for your help with this one.Now would you be able to help me so that my output When the only available date in xml is `<ApproximateDOB>3/4/1956</ApproximateDOB>` I want the output to look like this                                         
`<ext:PersonBirthDate> <ext:PersonBirthDate approximateDateIndicator="true" currentIndicator="true">1956-03-04</ext:PersonBirthDate>
</ext:PersonBirthDate>`                                             This means that the **currentIndicator="false" ** will instead be **currentIndicator="true". I am not sure how to change the code.

Comment: It may be best to ask a whole new question, I think, as that wasn't in the scope of the originally question. Having said that, you could do something like `currentIndicator="{@Current = 'true' or count(../ApproximateDOB|../DateOfBirth) = 1 }"`

Comment: Thanks for the help. however I am not sure where to add that piece of code.  Where do you recommend adding this code? I will also submit a new question as you suggested.

Comment: There is already a line in the XSLT for `currentIndicator="{@Current = 'true'}"`. Just replace that line with the new code.