# How do I remove parent node for output and display only children without the parent?

Tags: xml, xslt

My output from the xslt below is displaying like this:

```
<ext:PersonBirthDate>
    <ext:PersonBirthDate approximateDateIndicator="true" currentIndicator="false">1956-03-04</ext:PersonBirthDate>
    <ext:PersonBirthDate ext:approximateDateIndicator="false" ext:currentIndicator="false">1956-04-21</ext:PersonBirthDate>
    <ext:PersonBirthDate ext:approximateDateIndicator="false" ext:currentIndicator="true">1956-05-21</ext:PersonBirthDate>
</ext:PersonBirthDate>
```

As you can see the parent node **ext:PersonBirthDate** has 3 children with the same name. 
**How do I remove the parent in the output and just display the 3 children nodes.**

**I want my output to look like this:**

```
<ext:PersonBirthDate approximateDateIndicator="true" currentIndicator="false">1956-03-04</ext:PersonBirthDate>
<ext:PersonBirthDate ext:approximateDateIndicator="false" ext:currentIndicator="false">1956-04-21</ext:PersonBirthDate>
<ext:PersonBirthDate ext:approximateDateIndicator="false" ext:currentIndicator="true">1956-05-21</ext:PersonBirthDate>
```

**XML document**

```
<Party ID="14474176" InternalPartyID="1612366618">
    <Gender Word="F ">Female</Gender>
    <ApproximateDOB>3/4/1956</ApproximateDOB>
    <DateOfBirth>04/21/1956</DateOfBirth>
    <DateOfBirth Current="true">05/21/1956</DateOfBirth>
</Party>
```

**Here is my xslt code slightly changed from the original**

```
<!--Templates for DateOfBirth for the respondent-->
     <xsl:template match="DateOfBirth">
       <ext:PersonBirthDate>
          <xsl:attribute name="ext:approximateDateIndicator">false</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="ext:currentIndicator">false</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="mscef:formatDate(string(.))"/>
       </ext:PersonBirthDate>
     </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="DateOfBirth[@Current='true']">
         <ext:PersonBirthDate>
             <xsl:attribute name="ext:approximateDateIndicator">false</xsl:attribute>
             <xsl:attribute name="ext:currentIndicator">true</xsl:attribute>
             <xsl:value-of select="mscef:formatDate(string(.))"/>
         </ext:PersonBirthDate>
       </xsl:template>

<!--Templates for ApproximateDOB for the respondent-->
      <xsl:template match="ApproximateDOB">
          <ext:PersonBirthDate approximateDateIndicator="true" currentIndicator="{not(../DateOfBirth)}" >
          <xsl:value-of select="mscef:formatDate(string(.))"/>
        </ext:PersonBirthDate>
      </xsl:template>

<!--Respondent Template-->
    <xsl:template name="Respondent">
        <xsl:param name="pProtectionOrderID"/>
        <ext:Respondent>
<!--Guardian -->
    <xsl:for-each select="//CaseParty[(Connection[(@Word='GRD')])][1]">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Party[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]">
            <xsl:call-template name="Guardian"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ApproximateDOB|DateOfBirth"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </ext:Respondent>
 </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or shortly:

```
<xsl:template match="ApproximateDOB">
    <ext:PersonBirthDate approximateDateIndicator="true" currentIndicator="{count(../ApproximateDOB)=1}">
        <xsl:value-of select="mscef:formatDate(string(.))"/>
    </ext:PersonBirthDate>
</xsl:template>
```

Note: IMHO you would do well to combine all three DOB templates into one (as I believe was already suggested to you in your previous question).

---

### Edit:

> It's only true if the only element present is ApproximateDOB.

Ah. So we misunderstood the requirement. This could be achieved simply by changing:

```
<ext:PersonBirthDate approximateDateIndicator="true" currentIndicator="{count(../ApproximateDOB)=1}">
```

to:

```
<ext:PersonBirthDate approximateDateIndicator="true" currentIndicator="{count(../*)=1}">
```

However, based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26914010/how-do-i-display-all-the-date-of-birth-from-a-node), I suspect you don't mean that literally, as this would also return false when the Party has only an ApproximateDOB, but it also has a Gender. So you probably want to do:

```
<ext:PersonBirthDate approximateDateIndicator="true" currentIndicator="{not(../DateOfBirth)}">
```

instead, which will return true when there are no sibling DateOfBirth elements.

Comment: I have combined my templates into one. However when xml node as other date of birth like here below, the output is not as I want.                                                  `Party ID="1">                                                        <ApproximateDOB>3/4/1956</ApproximateDOB>
<DateOfBirth>04/21/1956</DateOfBirth>
<DateOfBirth Current="true">05/21/1956</DateOfBirth>            </Party>` I will edit the question and add xml document code so you understand what I have. I will also add the way I want the output to look.

Comment: @user3781064 Don't you have enough there to finish this on your own? Hopefully, you are learning something here, not just copy/pasting.

Comment: When there are 3 elements on the xml node, I get ApproximateDateIndicator="true" **currentIndicator="true"**. but When approximateIndicator="true" currentIndicator should be false `<ext:PersonBirthDate approximateDateIndicator="true" currentIndicator="true" DateOfBirthIndicator="false">1956-03-04</ext:PersonBirthDate><ext:PersonBirthDate ApproximateDateIndicator="false" CurrentIndicator="false" DateOfBirthIndicator="true">1956-04-21</ext:PersonBirthDate>
<ext:PersonBirthDate ApproximateDateIndicator="false" CurrentIndicator="true" DateOfBirthIndicator="false">1956-05-21</ext:PersonBirthDate>`

Comment: @user3781064 You get currentIndicator="true" if (and only if) the current parent `Party` element has exactly one `ApproximateDOB` child element - regardless of how many **other** child nodes it might have. -- P.S. Please don't post code in comments, it's difficult to read.

Comment: I would like to add **ext:** in front of **approximateDateIndicator**, **DateOFBirthIndicator**, and **CurrentIndicator** but I am not sure how to go about it. I have posted here above the way I want the output to look.

Comment: @user3781064 I suggest you post a separate question about how to put attributes in a namespace (after searching for previous answers on this topic, of course). It has nothing to do with the problem discussed here.

Comment: @user3781064 Good. Please re-close this question, if we're done here.